# Show hidden drop down based on selected option in another drop down with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I'm trying to figure out how to show hidden div but I'm a little rusty on jQuery.

So when a user selects "Yes" from Menu1 dropdown, I want the Menu2 dropdown to show up. l'm using `style="visibility: hidden;` to hide Menu2.

[image]
[image]

```
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputEmail4">Menu1</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="name" id="Menu1">
                <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        **<div class="form-group col-md-4" style="visibility: hidden;">**
            <label for="inputPassword4">Menu2</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="pets" id="Menu2">
                <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
                <option value="dog">Dog</option>
                <option value="cat">Cat</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: use `onchange` event on menu1 and check if the value of selectbox is `Yes` then `.show()` that div or `.hide()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this siple javascript code for that.
No need to go for jQuery here.
just give a id to hidden div so we can access it.

```js
        document.getElementById('Menu1').onchange = e => {
            let hiddenElement = document.getElementById('hiddenDiv')
            e.target.value == 'Yes' ?
                hiddenElement.style.visibility = 'visible' :
                hiddenElement.style.visibility = 'hidden'
        }
```

```html
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputEmail4">Menu1</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="name" id="Menu1">
            <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    **<div class="form-group col-md-4" id='hiddenDiv' style="visibility: hidden;">**
        <label for="inputPassword4">Menu2</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="pets" id="Menu2">
            <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
            <option value="dog">Dog</option>
            <option value="cat">Cat</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it very easily in jQuery using the `show` and `hide` functions:

```
    $("#Menu2Container").hide(); 
  
    $("#Menu1").on("change", function(){  
        if ($(this).val()=="Yes")
           $("#Menu2Container").show();
        else
           $("#Menu2Container").hide();
    });
```

**How this works:**

1. First give a class or id to #Menu2's container so you can target it in your jQuery, e.g. `<div id="Menu2Container">`
2. Hide your Menu2 container in the jQuery when the page loads
3. Add an event handler for change events on `#Menu1` to detect  when an option is selected.
4. In the handler, get the value of the selected option using `val()`
5. If "Yes" is selected, `show()` the `#Menu2Container`, otherwise `hide()` it

**Working Example:**

```js
$("#Menu2Container").hide();
 
$("#Menu1").on("change", function(){  
    if ($(this).val()=="Yes")
       $("#Menu2Container").show();
    else
       $("#Menu2Container").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputEmail4">Menu1</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="name" id="Menu1">
                <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4" id="Menu2Container">
            <label for="inputPassword4">Menu2</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="pets" id="Menu2">
                <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
                <option value="dog">Dog</option>
                <option value="cat">Cat</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Note: I would suggest considering if the grid `col` is the best container to hide for the menu - this obviously depends on your layout, but showing and hiding the col will affect the grid layout and could affect the overall appearance.

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla Javascript:

You can use an event listener to change the visibility to visible.

Set a conditional in your event handler and set the handler to change, check to see if the value of the target of your event listener is set to the desired value `Yes`, if it is, then set the div to visible...

I did add an ID to your DIV to target it directly...

```js
let showMe = document.getElementById("showMe");

let menu1 = document.getElementById("Menu1");


menu1.addEventListener("change", function(e){
  if(this.value === 'Yes'){
     showMe.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="inputEmail4">Menu1</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="name" id="Menu1">
      <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
      <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  **
  <div id="showMe" class="form-group col-md-4" style="visibility: hidden;">**
    <label for="inputPassword4">Menu2</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="pets" id="Menu2">
      <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
      <option value="dog">Dog</option>
      <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (short form of `if` and `else`)

Along with jQuery functions like => [show()](https://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) function to display your second `menu2` when you select `Yes`

Just add this code in jQuery:

```
const $Menu2 = $("#Menu2Container") //element
$Menu2.hide(); //Initially hide

//Change function
$("#Menu1").on("change", function() {
  $(this).val() == "Yes" ? $Menu2.show() : $Menu2.hide();
});
```

Live working demo:

```js
const $Menu2 = $("#Menu2Container") //element
//Initially hide
$Menu2.hide();
//Chage function
$("#Menu1").on("change", function() {
  $(this).val() == "Yes" ? $Menu2.show() : $Menu2.hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="inputEmail4">Menu1</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="name" id="Menu1">
      <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
      <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4" id="Menu2Container">
    <label for="inputPassword4">Menu2</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="pets" id="Menu2">
      <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
      <option value="dog">Dog</option>
      <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: Great minds think alike... you called your id `#Menu2Container` too! :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Ahh did not even notice i think what happened was when i copied the OP's HTML i might have picked up yours :) i thought that's what OP is using. Thanks :)